# what would be the value stored after '&' operation

Tags: c, microcontroller, i2c, keil

In the Code below

```
void I2C_Write(uint8_t v_i2cData_u8)
{
    uint8_t i;

    for(i=0;i<8;i++)                   // loop 8 times to send 1-byte of data
    {
        SDA_PIN = v_i2cData_u8 & 0x80;     // Send Bit by Bit on SDA line
        i2c_Clock();                   // Generate Clock at SCL
        v_i2cData_u8 = v_i2cData_u8<<1;// Bring the next bit to be transmitted to MSB position
    }

    i2c_Clock();
}
```

in the statement: SDA_PIN = v_i2cData_u8 & 0x80; it is told that data will be sent bit by bit,if data is sent bit by bit then what will be stored in SDA_PIN,will SDA_PIN have the value = 0x80 or 1?

Comment: `SDA_PIN` will have the value `0x80` if the leftmost bit of `v_i2cData_u8` is set.

Answer (score 0):

SDA_PIN will be assigned either `0x80` (128) or `0` depending on the high order bit of `v_i2cData_u8` in that loop.  If you want to insure a `0x01` byte is written, you would need to do this:

`SDA_PIN = (v_i2cData_u8 & 0x80) ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: Same as in the answer above